# Unix systems restarting on it's own

Tags: unix

Hy Guys,

Our Unix server is just starting on it's own. I just see a message stating
New Run Level 6
System is coming down please wait.....

What can I do to troublehsoot this issue?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What type of Unix? What troubleshooting have you done so far? The log message you referenced seems to point to a graceful shutdown being triggered by something. Any cron jobs? Any other users on the system?

Comment: I am really not a Unix guy, I am Windows guys, just trying to help my friend. I think the version is 5.0, the system runa cron job but from another computer over telnet.

Comment: What type of Unix? Cron jobs are like Scheduled Tasks in Windows, they aren't run remotely. Try this command and see what it says `cat /etc/crontab`. Also see if `tail /var/log/messages` says anything like "System shutdown initiated by root at [time]."

Comment: it's saying crontab doesn't exist and /var/log/messages doesn't exists
in var/log/ I only see a directory called cups

Comment: I cannot begin to imagine what you or someone else has done to that server to get it to this state, but if you only have one file under /var/log, chances are good that it's time for a restore from backup.  You *do* have a backup, right?

Comment: I agree with BMDan, sounds like the system might be hosed if there's almost nothing under /var/log. A Kernel fault might well be what's causing the reboots, a result of file corruption or something similar.

Comment: Just not enough info for any kind of useful response.  What OS? "uname -a" will tell you.  Not all Unixes are the same, and not all of them put the useful stuff in /var/log/.

Answer (score 1):

Try unplugging the front panel power switch.  Seriously, we had a Dell machine that was turning itself on and off at random times.  The log showed what appeared to be a graceful shutdown, but then four seconds later the entries stopped, and started up again a couple hours later (when it turned itself back on).

It was as though someone was holding in the power button, forcing a power down after four seconds.  I unplugged the front panel connector and haven't had a problem since.

Comment: I've heard of layoffs fixing that issue as well. A Netware server that was accessible was randomly rebooting for no obvious reason, then a round of layoffs, and the problem stopped occurring.

Comment: Layoffs as in people were fired?